# Bootstrap: Multiple Modal Windows with JS on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

i have a little problem. I have two different Modal Windows. In each Window are Buttons with different JS Functions.

My first Modal Window have a submit Button (#subButton) and fire this JS

```
 $('#subButton').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    doSubmit();
});
```

My Second Modal Window have a delete Button (#delButton) and should fire this JS

```
  $('#delButton').on('click', function (e) {

    if (confirm('Are you Sure?')) {
      e.preventDefault();
      doDelete();
     }
});
```

The Problem is, that only the first Modal Window-Button work. The second Modal show up correctly but his Button don't work.

My PHP looks like :

```
 <div id="SubmitModal" class="modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel1"
     aria-hidden="true">
  ...
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="subButton">Send</button>
  ...
  ...
   <div id="DeleteModal" class="modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel1"
     aria-hidden="true">
  ...
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="delButton">Send</button>
```

If I change the order of the Modal Windows only the first work. 
What should I change? Booth JS Functions work

Greetings

Comment: if i put the Modal Windows into a separate File and include it to my main file, it works!

Comment: try like `$(document).on('click', '#delButton', function (e)`